# CAN bus communication. Issue with two slaves having same CAN ID

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, can, canopen

Does anyone know if it is possible to have CAN offsetting in case two slaves in same circuit transmits different data in same ID?? I have two slaves with same CAN ID transmitting data and I cannot change the IDs but I need to capture both data for further processing. I heard something about offsetting the CAN ID of one to get both data for post-processing but could not find much material. Thank you

Comment: I've never heard of something called *CAN ID Offsetting*. Could you provide a reference or resource mentioning it? Also, the model & documentation of the device in question can also be helpful, in case you're missing something.

Comment: You should be concerned to have the tags Arduino + CANopen in the same question. Implementing CANopen on a 8 bit AVR which doesn't even have an internal CAN controller is sheer self-torture. If you want to use CANopen, then pick a suitable MCU. Arduino is suitable for electronic waste recycling, but little else.

Comment: In 2022 "Arduino" certainly does not imply an architecture target (let alone 8-bit)... It could be an STM32 or any ARM core theoretically

Answer (score 1):

Offsets, as used in for example CANopen, are based on CAN identifiers (called "COBID" in CANopen). You'll have an identifier such as for example 0x200 + node id. So one node with id 1 sends data with 0x201 identifier and another with node id 2 sends it with 0x202 and so on. This enables up to 127 nodes to send the same data without caring about timing between each other.

Also, in case of CANopen specifically, you can change COBID of certain PDOs by SDO accessing the PDO communication settings in the OD, preferably during the pre-operational phase at start-up.

The only other option is time multiplexing, where you ensure that two nodes never send the same data at the same time. One way to achieve this is to have a supervisor node provide a sync message that is sent cyclically once per 10ms/100ms etc. Then each node may send its data with a time offset from the point where it receives the sync. Such systems must be fully deterministic though, you cannot afford some higher priority message occupying the bus and delaying these "time offset" messages. You also need to calculate the transmit time for all frames on the bus given the baudrate.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strictly forbidding two nodes to send the same communication object ID. The receiving nodes however can't distinguish between them and arbitration can get tricky (since they would truly conflict on the bus).

The idea is that CAN IDs are not like node addresses in the sense of Ethernet MACs but they are only 'message labels' for arbitration purpose; some protocol even embed data in the CAN ID. Upper level protocols will dictate the assignment policy.

As for the offseting, the most similar thing I've seen is that for duplex communication 'id' is used in one direction and 'id+n' is for the other one (n is likely 1 or 8) but I don't think that's what you mean.